# Custom button with custom state

Tags: android

I created a custom button class (I followed this topic: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)

Now I would like create a custom state (state_avaibility), I created a new attribut attrs.xml :

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomButton">
    <attr name="state_available" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

I wanted to use

```
 StateListDrawable mNormalDrawable;
 mNormalDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
 mNormalDrawable.addState(new int[]{R.attr.state_available}, createAvailableDrawable(attr));
```

But this method doesn't accept custom state.

Do you know how can I create a custom button (create programmatically) and add custom state?

EDIT:

I created two buttons (available and unavailable), I have two method to do that:

```
private LayerDrawable createAvailableDrawable(TypedArray attr) {
LayerDrawable drawableAvailable = (LayerDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.button_available).mutate();

// Some modifications with custom attributs
   return drawableAvailable;
}

private LayerDrawable createUnavailableDrawable(TypedArray attr) {
LayerDrawable drawableUnavailable = (LayerDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.button_unavailable).mutate();

// Some modifications with custom attributes 
   return drawableUnavailable;
}
```

After I had a new custom attribute:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomButton">
    <attr name="state_available" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Then I overrode onCreateDrawableState method:

```
@Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);

        if (mIsAvailable) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_AVAILABLE);
        }

        return drawableState;
    }
```

Then I tried this:

```
 StateListDrawable mNormalDrawable;
 mNormalDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
 mNormalDrawable.addState(new int[]{R.attr.state_available}, createAvailableDrawable(attr));
mNormalDrawable.addState(new int[]{-R.attr.state_available}, createUnavailableDrawable(attr));
```

---

Now I add the button:

```
<mobile.custom.com.library.Widget.CustomButton
        android:id="@+id/CustomButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:vd_cornerRadius="5dp"
        custom:vd_color_text_unavailable="@color/yellow"
        custom:vd_text_available="@string/available"
        custom:vd_text_unavailable="@string/unavailable"
        custom:state_available="false" />
```

Now when I change the value of custom:state_available, the button doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `CustomButton`, class override `onCreateDrawableState`, to *merge* your custom state:

```
private static final int[] STATE_AVAILABLE = { R.attr.state_available };

@Override
public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
    if (available) {
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_AVAILABLE);
    }
    return drawableState;
}
```

`mergeDrawableStates` will merge your custom state, `STATE_AVAILABLE` into the base states

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already used this, but after, can I use : 
`mNormalDrawable.addState(new int[] { R.attr.state_available }, createAvailableDrawable(attr));
            mUnavailableDrawable.addState(new int[] { -R.attr.state_available }, createNormalDrawable(attr));`   ?

Comment: I misread your question. Sorry about that. What's the issue ? Why can't you add the custom state through addState?

Comment: I created two button programmatically, I created a new atribute (

Comment: I created two button programmatically, I created a new attribute (state_available). 

But when I add my custom button on the XML layout like that:   <mobile.custom.com.library.Widget.CustomButton
        android:id="@+id/videodeskButton"
        custom:vd_color_text_unavailable="@color/yellow"
        custom:vd_text_available="@string/available"
        custom:vd_text_unavailable="@string/unavailable"
        custom:state_available="false" />

When I change custom:state_available ="true", nothing happens

Comment: can you update your question with the relevant code (which is not working)

Comment: looks good. Do you need to change a drawable accordingly to the custom state?

Comment: It's working, the problem wasn't mNormalDrawable.addState(new int[]{R.attr.state_available}, createAvailableDrawable(attr)); but the function createAvailableDrawable(attr)

Thank you for your help